# Aligning button backgrounds to pixel boundaries in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm having trouble with getting exact locations and sizes when creating background graphics for my buttons. I can never get a clean x pixels by y pixels - it always ends up having a couple decimal places. This happens for the both the size and location of the shape.

I have snapping on, but it doesn't seem to be working. How can I ensure that everything is precise?

Comment: When you say you have snapping on, are you talking about "Align Edges", "Snap Vector Tools and Transforms to Pixel Grid" or are you using Snap To > Grid? "Snap Vector Tools and Transforms to Pixel Grid" is the one you want (Photoshop CS6 only... there's a similar option for versions prior to CS6).

Answer (score 3):

The grid settings were messed up from when I was trying to figure this stuff out before.

I went to Edit > Preferences > Guides, Grids, and Slices, and changed gridlines to every 1 pixel with 1 pixel subdivisions.